# What does the region look like?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I am asked to calculate the double integral over the triangle R defined by $-x\tan (\alpha) \le y \le x\tan (\alpha)$ and $x \le 1$. It is also noted that $\alpha$ is an acute angle. I am having a hard time conceptualizing this.

Comment: Can you draw the line $y = \tan\alpha x$ first?

Comment: Hint: $y=x \tan\alpha$ is a straight line through the origin at an angle $\alpha$ to the $x$-axis

Answer (score 0):

Divide through by $x$ to get

$$-\tan\alpha\le \frac yx\le\tan\alpha$$

Since $\arctan(\cdot)$ is an increasing function everywhere, we can simply apply it to all sides to get

$$-\alpha\le \arctan\left(\frac yx\right)\le\alpha$$
$$\left|\arctan\left(\frac yx\right)\right|\le\alpha$$

The last step was somewhat superfluous. You could read from the first line that the angle between the x-axis and the point $(x,y)$ must be less than $\alpha$ in absolute value.

Alternatively you could also draw the lines $x\tan\alpha$, $-x\tan\alpha$ and $x=1$ and shade in the bounded region on the right.

Comment: Alright, so I get the area now.  That was a great description. I am asked to integrate $x^2+y^2$.  Am I correct in converting to polar coordinates and integrating $r^3 dr d\theta$ with r from 0 to $1/cos (\theta)$ and $\theta$ from $-\alpha $ to $\alpha $?